# Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, phonegap

I'm developing a mobile application with Ionic 1. I tried to build it on build.phonegap but after the compilation I faced such an error in log file. Log file contains this error:

> Command finished with error code 1: /project/gradlew
>   cdvBuildDebug,-b,/project/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
>   Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files
>   use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4'. Resolved versions for compilation
>   (25.4.0) and packaging (28.0.0-alpha3) differ. This can generate
>   runtime errors due to mismatched resources.

After this error I deleted this line;

`<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" source="npm" />`

from the config file inside the www folder, and the problem was solved. But at the end, I need this plugin in my application.

PS: I searched this issue on many sources but because of phonegap I shouldn't solve this problem by changing the .gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by at least one other plugin in your project referencing a different version of the Android Support Library than `de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification`.

If you were building locally, you could, as you mentioned, edit the `.gradle` config files manually to resolve this.

Or you could use the [cordova-android-support-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release) plugin to automatically align the support library versions.
However, this plugin relies on Cordova hook scripts which are [not supported by Phonegap Build](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/425).

So to resolve this issue in the Phonegap Build environment, your only option as I see it is to fork the problematic plugins, manually align the support library versions referenced in their `plugin.xml` / `.gradle` files, and reference these forked plugins in your project's `config.xml`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I have another question. I checked every files in the project and all the `de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification` plugins have the same version. Maybe I skipped an important file, where should I check it and if I reference this .gradle file in .config file, will my problem resolve ? How to do it ? too many questions, forgive me :) And again thank you.